# Java - try catch seems to be causing a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java

I have a code block which takes from the user a number and a string. The string is later used to read in data from a file whose name is that of the string.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number: ");
int number = scanner.nextInt();
if(number <= 1){
   System.out.println("Number must be 2 or more.");
   return;
   }
System.out.print("Enter the name of the text file: ");
String fileName = scanner.next();
```

However, when I try to wrap this code in a try-catch, as shown:

```
try{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    if(number <= 1){
        System.out.println("Number must be 2 or more.");
        return;
     }
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the text file: ");
    String fileName = scanner.next();
 }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
 }
```

It seems to always cause this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Even though i have not changed the file location or any other aspects of the code.

What is the reason this is happening?

Comment: You have changed other aspects of the code, otherwise the "other" code would not compile without the `fileName` variable. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and the full exception message, specially the stacktrace.

Comment: Well, I don't believe that this code alone is causing a `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...catch blocks in Java are scoped. Move the declaration of any variables you need to use later outside of the try...catch block. Generally you want to put as little code as possible inside a try...catch block anyway, so this is good practice.

For example:

```
String filename;
int number;
try{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    number = scanner.nextInt();
    if(number <= 1){
        System.out.println("Number must be 2 or more.");
        return;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the text file: ");
    fileName = scanner.next();
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I have solved the issue.